# Why aren't React components displayed?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying my hand at studying react. I want to create a simple template from bootstrap components, but react doesn't see the components when compiling.

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './hocs/Layout';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Blog from './components/Blog';
import BlogDetail from './components/BlogDetail';
import Category from './components/Category';

function App() {
    return(
        <Router>
        <Layout>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/blog' component={Blog} />
                <Route exact path='/blog/:id' component={BlogDetail} />
                <Route exact path='/category/:id' component={Category} />
            </Routes>
        </Layout>
    </Router>
    );
};

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Home.js

```
import React from "react";

function Home(){
    return(
        <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

```
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'

const Layout = (props) =>(
    <div>
        <Navbar />
        {props.children}
    </div>
);

export default Layout
```

p.s. Navbar react sees, but the home component does not. There is no code even in the console, although they are identical in content.

Each route should show the layout navbar and load the component that is called by the route. Layout and Navbar are seen by the reactor, but everything else is not even reflected in the browser console.

Comment: Show us the Layout component, that's likely where the problem is.

Comment: @Eduardoeduardo-motta-de-moraes I do not know how to add the code to the answer, so I added it to the body of the question. I think I understand what you mean, but I don't know how to solve the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can upgrade to [v6](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) and use an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) component in your `Layout` to do what you want using react-router-dom.

The Outlet allows nested UI to show up when child routes are rendered.

```js
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <main>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Also, your `App` component would need to be refactored like this:

```js
function App() {
  return(
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='blog' element={<Blog />} />           
          <Route path='blog/:id' element={<BlogDetail />} />
          <Route path='category/:id' element={<Category />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
  </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: Okay, I added it, but it still doesn't show home. Do I need to add the home tag to the layout as well?

Comment: It all worked, thank you very much!